# java beginner programming, putting strings in char array to filter input

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

in this code I've been trying to filter the characters in the array with a for-loop to a second array, but am unable to. Could anyone tell me what is exactly wrong with my code?

```
public class Deel1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String zinInvoer = getInput();
        String zinUitvoer = filterZin(zinInvoer);
    }

    static String getInput() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String zinInvoer = "";

        System.out.println("Voer een zin in: ");
        if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            zinInvoer = scan.nextLine().trim();
        }

        if (zinInvoer.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Geen invoer!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return zinInvoer;
    }

    static String filterZin(String zinInvoer) {
        String zinUitvoer = "";
        char ongefilterd[] = zinInvoer.toCharArray();
        String nogFilteren = new String(ongefilterd);
        char a = nogFilteren.charAt(97);
        for (a = 97; a <= 122; a++) {
            a = a += 32;  
            char gefilterd[] = //second array to be printed
        }
        System.out.println("Gefilterd: " + zinUitvoer);
        return zinInvoer;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problems with arrays is they need to know how long they need to be in advance.  Might be better to use a `StringBuilder` instead...

Comment: `a = a += 32;` this line is suspicious, modifying your index inside the for loop, is not a good way to do i think then your `a++` seems to be useless..

Comment: There are so many strange things in your code that I am not even getting what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The reason for that is because I want to modify the unicode and change the results of the filtered string. I am not allowed to use the replaceall methode for my assignment, hence the hairy code.
Sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: Do you try to convert lower case letters to upper case in the string?

Comment: @MadProgrammer In this case, we know the maximum length of the output, so we can do `new char[maxLength]` then take advantage of the [`String(char[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[],%20int,%20int)) constructor and pass in the final length, but there's still a lot of weirdness in this code regardless of that..

Comment: @Brian To lazy to be bothered ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it annoys you but I had to translate your variables into english in order to figure out what their purposes were.

First of all, it will always throw an exception when the string is less than 98 letters long because it looks for the 97th letter.
Second, the for loop in "filterZin" will only filter letter # 98, which I am guessing was not your intention.
Also, geFilterd should probably be created outside of the for loop, and in the for loop you (i guess) would want to do

```
geFilterd[a]=a+32;
a+=32;
```

Because I couldn't figure out what your overall goal was for this program, I made a version of it that does what I think you were trying to do, but again, I do not know.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Deel1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String phraseInput = getInput();
    filterPhrase(phraseInput);
}

static String getInput() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String phraseInput = "";

    System.out.println("Voer een zin in: ");
    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        phraseInput = scan.nextLine().trim();
    }

    if (phraseInput.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Geen invoer!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return phraseInput;
}

static String filterPhrase(String phraseInput) {
    String phraseOutput = "";
    char onFiltered[] = phraseInput.toCharArray();
    String currentFilter = new String(onFiltered);

//        for (a = 97; a <= 122; a++) {
//            a = a += 32;  
//            //char filtered[] = //second array to be printed
//        }
    char[] filtered = new char[26];
    for(int i=97;i<=122;i++){
        char a = currentFilter.charAt(i);
        filtered[i-97]= (char) (a+32);
    }
    System.out.println("filtered: " + filtered.toString());
    return phraseInput;
}
}
```